# Is it a part of the trait when it got extended?

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
object ServerStreamer {

  sealed trait Ack

  object Ack extends Ack

  sealed trait ServerHealthStreamer

  case class Init(ackTo: ActorRef[Ack]) extends ServerHealthStreamer

  case object Complete extends ServerHealthStreamer

  case class Fail(ex: Throwable) extends ServerHealthStreamer

  sealed trait SapHealthStreamer extends ServerHealthStreamer

  case class SapMessage(ackTo: ActorRef[Ack], msg: SapHealthEvent) extends SapHealthStreamer

  sealed trait KafkaHealthStreamer extends ServerHealthStreamer

  case class KafkaMessage(ackTo: ActorRef[Ack], msg: KafkaHealthEvent) extends KafkaHealthStreamer

}
```

and I would like to know, if for example `Complete` is a type of `SapHealthStreamer`, that I can use for pattern matching.

For instanace, the pattern matching will look like this:

```
val value: SapHealthStreamer = Complete


value match {
   case Init =>
    ???
   case Complete =>
    ??? 
   case Fail =>
    ???     
   case d:SapMessage =>
    ???    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: Is for example `Complete` a type of `SapHealthStreamer`? Can I include `Complete` in the pattern matching clause, when a variable is an instance of  `SapHealthStreamer`?

Comment: @Jasper-M I updatet my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Complete is a type of SapHealthStreamer

It is not, it's a value of type `ServerHealthStreamer` (but not of type `SapHealthStreamer`)

> For instanace, the pattern matching will look like this:

The first line will fail to compile due to incompatible types. Assuming you meant

```
val value: ServerHealthStreamer = Complete
```

instead, yes, you can match `Complete` like this. The problem is with `case Init` and `case Fail` which will match their companion objects instead of types and that's probably not what you want (you should get an error message because those companion objects have incompatible types with `value` and so can never match).

```
value match {
   case Init(ackTo) => // or case d: Init and use d.ackTo
    ???
   case Complete =>
    ??? 
   case Fail(ex) =>
    ???     
   case SapMessage(ackTo, msg) =>
    ???    
}
```

Comment: @Jasper-M Thanks, I wasn't attentive enough.

Comment: How it is possible, when `val value: ServerHealthStreamer` that I can pattern match with `SapMessage`?

Comment: @zero_coding `SapMessage` is a subtype of `ServerHealthStreamer`.

Comment: I did not know that, the subtype can be pattern match on supertype. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If `value` is a `ServerHealthStreamer`, that means it *can* be a `SapMessage` (or a `KafkaMessage`, or `Complete`, or ...) so it makes sense to be able to test that in a pattern match.